# Debouncing MUI Autocomplete not working properly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement `debounce` for mui autocomplete,
but it's not working well.

I want to send a debounced request to server when `inputValue` change.

Am I miss something?

It looks `loadData` fired every input change. Only first load `debounce` works.

https://codesandbox.io/s/debounce-not-working-j4ixgg?file=/src/App.js

Here's the code from the sandbox:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { debounce } from "lodash";
import topFilms from "./topFilms";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  const loadData = () => {
    // sleep(1000)
    const filteredOptions = topFilms.filter((f) =>
      f.title.includes(inputValue)
    );
    // This log statement added by Ryan Cogswell to show why it isn't working.
    console.log(
      `loadData with ${filteredOptions.length} options based on "${inputValue}"`
    );
    setOptions(filteredOptions);
  };

  const debouncedLoadData = useCallback(debounce(loadData, 1000), []);

  const handleInputChange = (e, v) => {
    setInputValue(v);
    debouncedLoadData();
  };

  const handleChange = (e, v) => {
    setValue(v);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        disablePortal
        options={options}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.title === value.title}
        id="combo-box-demo"
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The link's code in topFilms.js is empty.

Comment: @MOLLY Sorry, I forgot to saving it. Please check the link again :)

Comment: @ton1 When you saved the edit to your sandbox, it probably changed the URL as well. I'll update it in a moment with one that has a film list plus some logging.

Comment: Given the `loadData` function will be a new instance every render, I'm not sure `lodash.debounce` will work as expected. Is there a reason you are avoiding the `useEffect` hook? Normally, I'd see the delay/debounce in the a `useEffect` that has the input `value` state as dependency.

Comment: @SmujMaiku The debounce works due to the `useCallback`, but there are other issues with the code. I'm in the middle of writing an answer describing what is going on.

Comment: I see, it's a bit cheeky in the implementation don't you think? Doesn't leave room for avoiding race conditions when that `// sleep` is replaced with a network call. I look forward to seeing what you've come up with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[tldr: codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/debounce-not-working-forked-yr7zv8?file=/src/App.js)

You can accomplish this with a few hooks working together. First lets look at a hook for debouncing state:

```js
function useDebounce(value, delay, initialValue) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("delaying", value);
    const timer = setTimeout(() => setState(value), delay);

    // clear timeout should the value change while already debouncing
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, [value, delay]);

  return state;
}
```

The above takes in a value and returns the debounced value from the hook later.
The callback at the end of the useEffect prevents a bunch of timers triggering one after the other.

Then your component can be reduced to:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  const debouncedValue = useDebounce(inputValue, 1000);

  // fetch data from server
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("fetching", debouncedValue);
    const filteredOptions = topFilms.filter((f) =>
      f.title.includes(debouncedValue)
    );
    setOptions(filteredOptions);
  }, [debouncedValue]);

  const handleInputChange = (e, v) => {
    setInputValue(v);
  };

  const handleChange = (e, v) => {
    setValue(v);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Autocomplete
        // props
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The useEffect here is run when the dependency `debouncedValue` is changed via react state business.
When typing in the TextField your console should look like:

```
delaying s
delaying sp
delaying spi
fetching spi
delaying spir
fetching spir
```

This `useEffect` in `App` leaves you with a good place to do your fetch to a server like you mentioned you'll need.
The `useEffect` could easily be replaced with something like [useQuery](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/overview#enough-talk-show-me-some-code-already)

Answer (score 3):

In your sandbox, `loadData` was being successfully debounced, however it was always executed with `inputValue === ""` which then matched all of the options. All of the actual filtering was then being immediately done by the `Autocomplete` component just the same as if you had provided the full set of options statically. Due to the behavior of JavaScript closures, `inputValue` is always the empty string because that is its initial value as you create the debounced version of `loadData`.

Whenever creating debounced functions, I recommend declaring and defining the original function and the debounced version at the top level rather than inside your component. Any local variables and state that your debounced function is dependent on can be passed in as arguments to the function (e.g. in my version of your code, the input value and the `setOptions` function are passed to `debouncedLoadData`). This avoids accidentally using stale values due to closure behavior and removes the need for `useCallback`.

Below is a reworked version of your code that moves `loadData` and `debouncedLoadData` to the top level. I also changed `loadData` to provide no data (rather than all data) when it is passed an empty string so that the debounce behavior is easier to see -- otherwise whenever the Autocomplete has the full set of options, the filtering will occur immediately based on the options that the Autocomplete already has. This also more closely simulates what real code would likely do (i.e. avoid calling the back end for empty string).

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { debounce } from "lodash";
import topFilms from "./topFilms";

const loadData = (inputValue, setOptions) => {
  if (inputValue.length === 0) {
    console.log("no options");
    setOptions([]);
    return;
  }
  const filteredOptions = topFilms.filter((f) =>
    f.title.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
  );
  console.log(
    `loadData with ${filteredOptions.length} options based on "${inputValue}"`
  );
  setOptions(filteredOptions);
};

const debouncedLoadData = debounce(loadData, 1000);

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  const handleInputChange = (e, v) => {
    setInputValue(v);
    debouncedLoadData(v, setOptions);
  };

  const handleChange = (e, v) => {
    setValue(v);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        disablePortal
        options={options}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.title === value.title}
        id="combo-box-demo"
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit debounce working]